# What is AJAX good for?

Tags: ajax

So far the things I can do with AJAX are handle requests and reload content.

...........

**What Else?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's it - but it's all about the consequence that results from this:

It allows you to keep a part of the application state on the client side (with traditional web pages, the entire browser DOM is reset for every request).

Answer (score 1):

It also helps you maintaining sessions for your customer. by sending every interval requests.